# Spree Starting Server

Tags: spree

I cloned the git repository onto a local machine and Amazon Web Services.

I've tried using `script/server` and `rails s`

The code is cloned using git://github.com/spree/spree.git

How do you start the server?

I'd rather use the full git so I can ultimately change the template.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section on the github page under "Working With Edge Source"
https://github.com/spree/spree

Clone the Git repo

```
git clone git://github.com/spree/spree.git
cd spree
```

Install the gem dependencies

```
bundle install
```

Create a sandbox Rails application for testing purposes (and automatically perform all necessary database setup)

```
bundle exec rake sandbox
```

Start the server

```
cd sandbox
rails server
```

I just checked it out and it works, but edge currently isn't working.  You might just want to fork it and use your own fork as a gem for a standard spree-store set up.

Comment: Can you image that virtual machine and load it to drop box?  Ha.

Comment: So I just cloned and I'm going to use the regular fork.  I didn't create a sandbox and just used bundle install and bundle exec rake within the spree folder and get rake aborted don't know how to build task.

Comment: As of this moment, there's a bug in sandbox.sh...  Easy fix, but there's other bugs in the edge install that make it blow up later that I haven't figured out yet.  How does one go about getting a *stable* version?